# I want to get data from ckeditor dynamically to the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have created a javascript which opens ckeditor on click event of div, and gets the data from the div to ckeditor, 
now i want something what can get that updated data from ckeditor back to that div again. and which happens dynamically.

I am using this javascript to get data from div

```
//var editor, html = '';
function createEditor(ele)
{
var x = ele.innerHTML;


CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(x);


 var y = document.getElementById("editor1").value;
alert(y);
//ele.innerHTML = y;
document.getElementById("editor1").style.display = "block";

}


    </script>
```

And my HTML is

```
 <div onclick="createEditor(this);" id="id2"> hello how r u? </div>
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I guess you want a live preview for CKEditor? You'll not be able to do this with the event `keyup`, but you can use CKEditor events like `key` (`instance.on('key', doSomething());`).

**Step 1:** Add two elements to the page:

1. textarea with ID: editor
2. div with ID: preview

```
...
<body>
    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
    <div id="preview"></div>
</body>
...
```

**Step 2:** Add javascript to detect `key` events and update `#preview`:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor'); //new ckeditor instance
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor; //reference to instance

//on `key` event
editor.on('key', function(){

  var data = editor.getData(); //reference to ckeditor data
  $('#preview').html(data); //update `div` html

});
```

**[I've created a preview in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iwunup/4).**

Answer (score 1):

I think, that binding onKeyUp event on your ckeditor textarea, should do the trick.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Comment: that can i do easily, but I am not getting any javascript idea to get data from ckeditor, CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData; is not giving the text

Comment: Please don't refer to w3schools.com as reference. http://w3fools.com/ Use MDN or other well-stablished resources. Thanks.

Comment: `var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();` this must work

Comment: @GBD yes I was using the same function but it replies something like function () {     var n = this;     n.fire("beforeGetData");     var l = n._.data;     if (typeof l != "string") {         var m = n.element;         if (m && n.elementMode == 1) {             l = m.is("textarea") ? m.getValue() : m.getHtml();         } else {             l = "";         }     }     l = {dataValue: l};     n.fire("getData", l);     return l.dataValue; }